# How to add ssr support for angular cli project using dotnet core as backend?

Tags: angular, webpack, .net-core, angular-cli, server-side-rendering

**What I did till now ?**

---

I started adding support for ssr with node express as backend refering [Angular Doc](https://next.angular.io/guide/universal) , and it worked as expected .

Then to make it support dotnet core instead of Node express , I used `@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine` referreing [universal doc](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/modules/aspnetcore-engine/README.md) .
And changed `server.ts` file in angular root folder and  `HomeController` in dotnet core project accordingly .

`"scripts": {
     ...
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run web:server && npm run webpack:server",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js",
}`

`build:ssr` command will generate the required files in the dist folder without errors.

And in my `HomeController` I added the path to the compiled `server.js` file like below .

```
        // Prerender / Serialize application (with Universal)
        var prerenderResult = await Prerenderer.RenderToString(
            "/", // baseURL
            nodeServices,
            cancelToken,
            new JavaScriptModuleExport(applicationBasePath + "../../../frontend/dist/server/server.js"),
            unencodedAbsoluteUrl,
            unencodedPathAndQuery,
            // Our Transfer data here will be passed down to Angular (within the main.server file)
            // Available there via `params.data.yourData`
            transferData,
            30000, // timeout duration
            Request.PathBase.ToString()
        );
```

And my `webpack.config.js` file to compile the `server.ts` file is shown below .

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const SERVER = 'server';

module.exports = {
  entry: {  server: './server.ts' },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/],
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, `dist/${SERVER}`),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
}
```

My `server.ts` file

```
// Polyfills
import 'es6-promise';
import 'es6-shim';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { INITIAL_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { createServerRenderer, RenderResult } from 'aspnet-prerendering';
// Grab the (Node) server-specific NgModule
import { AppServerModule } from './src/app/app.server.module';
// ***** The ASPNETCore Angular Engine *****
import { ngAspnetCoreEngine, IEngineOptions, createTransferScript } from '@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

enableProdMode(); // for faster server rendered builds

export default createServerRenderer(params => {

    /*
     * How can we access data we passed from .NET ?
     * you'd access it directly from `params.data` under the name you passed it
     * ie: params.data.WHATEVER_YOU_PASSED
     * -------
     * We'll show in the next section WHERE you pass this Data in on the .NET side
     */

    // Platform-server provider configuration
    const setupOptions: IEngineOptions = {
      appSelector: '<app-root></app-root>',
      ngModule: AppServerModule,
      request: params,
      providers: [
        /* Other providers you want to pass into the App would go here
        *    { provide: CookieService, useClass: ServerCookieService }

        * ie: Just an example of Dependency injecting a Class for providing Cookies (that you passed down from the server)
          (Where on the browser you'd have a different class handling cookies normally)
        */
      ]
    };

    // ***** Pass in those Providers & your Server NgModule, and that's it!
    return ngAspnetCoreEngine(setupOptions).then(response => {

      // Want to transfer data from Server -> Client?

      // Add transferData to the response.globals Object, and call createTransferScript({}) passing in the Object key/values of data
      // createTransferScript() will JSON Stringify it and return it as a <script> window.TRANSFER_CACHE={}</script>
      // That your browser can pluck and grab the data from
      response.globals.transferData = createTransferScript({
        someData: 'Transfer this to the client on the window.TRANSFER_CACHE {} object',
        fromDotnet: params.data.thisCameFromDotNET // example of data coming from dotnet, in HomeController
      });

      return ({
        html: response.html,
        globals: response.globals
      });

    });
});
```

**What am I still missing here? Is it not possible to use `angular cli` to build all the required files and use it in `createServerRenderer` ?**

Since Iam a noob in the area of ssr in angular & dotnetcore, I don't know how the main.js work along with the server.js file and all, Any help is much appreciated . Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered [the new ASP.NET Core Angular template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-2.0)? There's even a bit on running this will [SSR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-2.0#server-side-rendering).

Comment: Thanks for the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-2.0#server-side-rendering , I will check this out .

Comment: The new templates now use the Angular CLI. Pull it down, build a project, have a look. You might like what you see. It may save you a lot of time, too. I just migrated one I had from ng5 to ng6. Worked! I don't do the SSR stuff, but it looks like it is easy enough to add.

Comment: wow , I didn't saw the new update , Thanks @R.Richards.

Answer (score 0):

New Microsoft template is not working properly with Angular6 if you use 3rd party modules. Use Express instead of aspnetcore-engine